# If $a_{1}>2$and $a_{n+1}=a_{n}^{2}-2$ then Find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\frac{1}{a_{1}a_{2}......a_{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

**Question** If $a_{1}>2$and $\left\{ a_{n}\right\} be$ a recurrsive
sequence defined by setting $a_{n+1}=a_{n}^{2}-2$ then Find
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$\frac{1}{a_{1}a_{2}......a_{n}}$

[image]

**Book's Answer**[image: I have mentioned my problem]
I have mentioned my problem in the image.Any and all help will be appreciated

Comment: Isn't the question (as per answers) to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{1}a_{2}......a_{n}}$  instead of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\frac{1}{a_{1}a_{2}......a_{n}}$ which is written above?

Comment: @croraf I can add the question image if you want . Your comment is not readable .

Comment: I updated comment

Comment: @croraf Your question is already answered on mathstack by many methods,but all of them were  beyond my limits of understanding.I can only understand this particular method, and there was a doubt , which is clear now!

Comment: I think we are not on the same page. Can you add the img of the question above, instead of text?

Comment: @croraf I have added the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proven that

$$a_n^2-4 = a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2(a_1^2-4)$$

Divide both sides by $a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2$ and then take square root on both sides,

We have

$$\sqrt{\frac{a_n^2-4}{a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2}} = \sqrt{a_1^2-4}$$

Now take limit $n \to \infty$,

\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{a_n^2-4}{a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2}}   = \sqrt{a_1^2-4 }& \text{, note that RHS is independent of $n$.}\\
\sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n^2-4}{a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2}}   = \sqrt{a_1^2-4} & \text{ since square root is continuous}\\
\sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n^2}{a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2}- \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{4}{a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2}}   = \sqrt{a_1^2-4}\\
\sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n^2}{a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2}}   = \sqrt{a_1^2-4} & \text{, the $a_n$ increases to $\infty$, the second term vanishes}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{a_1 \ldots a_{n-1}}   = \sqrt{a_1^2-4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$a_{n}=a_{n-1}^{2}-2\implies a_n^2=a_{n-1}^{4}-4a_{n-1}-4\implies a_n^2-4=a_{n-1}^{2}(a_{n-1}^{2}-4) $$

thus
$$a_{n-1}^2-4=a_{n-2}^{2}(a_{n-2}^{2}-4) \implies a_n^2-4=a_{n-1}^{2}a_{n-2}^{2}(a_{n-2}^{2}-4) $$

and so on, thus it can be easily proved by induction that

$$a_n^2-4=a_{n-1}^{2}a_{n-2}^{2}...a_2^2a_1^2(a_1^{2}-4) $$

thus

$$\sqrt{a_1^{2}-4}= \frac{\sqrt{a_n^2-4}}{a_1a_2...a_{n-2}a_{n-1}}\sim\frac{a_n}{a_1a_2...a_{n-2}a_{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 2):

From $a_n^2-4 = a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2(a_1^2-4)$ one gets $\frac {a_n^2}{a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2}- \frac 4 {a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2}= (a_1^2-4)$ therefore $\frac {a_n}{a_1 \ldots a_{n-1}} = \sqrt {\frac 4 {a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2} + (a_1^2-4)} \tag 1$

Now, since $\lim a_n= +\infty$ it follows $\lim a_1^2 \ldots a_{n-1}^2 = +\infty$ therefore $\lim \frac {a_n}{a_1 \ldots a_{n-1}} = \sqrt {(a_1^2-4)}$

Comment: Although not the original question but how can we prove $\lim a_n= +\infty$?

Comment: @croraf Easy to prove $a_n \gt 2$ by induction. Then, $a_{n+1} - a_n = a_n^2 -a_n -2 = (a_n +1)(a_n -2) \gt 0$. Therefore $a_n$ has a limit. Suppose it is finite. Then $L =L^2 -2 $ with possible values $L=-1$ or $L=2$. First is not possible since $a_n \gt 2$, second not possible since $a_n$ is increasing.